# SSH: Login to local pc by key

Tags: ssh, debian, ssh-keys, public-key

I got a little problem.

I'm using apt-dater to keep different linux-systems updated.
Apt-dater uses ssh to login to these systems - there's no problem by doing this.

To connect to localhost, the system uses ssh monitor@localhost:port

I set up the user "monitor" on this localhost by doing this:

```
useradd -r -m monitor && mkdir /home/monitor/.ssh && chmod 700 /home/monitor/.ssh/ && chown monitor.monitor /home/monitor/.ssh

visudo
```

-> monitor ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/apt-get, /usr/bin/aptitude

```
nano /home/monitor/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

-> Insert public key of localhost's root

If I try to connect I'm still asked for a password. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure

.ssh and authorized_keys are both owned by monitor and belong to group monitor

run this successively:

Owner: `chown monitor /home/monitor/.ssh`
Group: `chown :monitor /home/monitor/.ssh/authorized_keys`

Owner: `chown monitor /home/monitor/.ssh`
Group: `chown :monitor /home/monitor/.ssh/authorized_keys`

**ALSO**: Share with us output of

`ls -al /home/monitor/.ssh` & `ls -al /home/monitor/.ssh/authorized_keys`

Comment: Hi there, this is the output of ls -al /home/monitor/.ssh:

drwx------ 2 monitor monitor 4096 Jun 12 11:28 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 monitor monitor 4096 Jun 12 11:27 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 monitor monitor  393 Jun 12 11:55 authorized_keys

This is the output of ls -al /home/monitor/.ssh/authorized_keys:

monitor monitor 393 Jun 12 11:55 /home/monitor/.ssh/authorized_keys

Comment: Here is a screenshot where you can see the results more conveniently: http://d.pr/i/1cbBW

Comment: This is the verbose output: http://d.pr/n/1g38m